# How to hide HTML elements before they load on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list with a customized "New" and "Edit" forms. I'm using jQuery to hide certain fields on `$(document).ready()`.

What happens on page load is that you see all the fields shown (for a split second) before they become hidden. It's a little unpleasant to see that flash-like transition.

Is there any way to manipulate the style of the HTML elements before they are loaded? (i.e.: display: none)

Sample code:

```
$(document).ready() {
    // Hides fields 1 and 3 on page load
    // Users can see it being hidden in fraction of a second
    $('#field-1').hide();
    $('#field-3').hide();
}
```

Comment: you basically answered the question yourself. just hide them with plain css using `display:none`. Maybe add a class to the `body` - tag that is used to hide all children and just remove this class when everything is loaded

Comment: Use CSS instead of JavaScript?

Comment: @GNi33 Hi, the issue is that SharePoint doesn't put an id nor class to these <tr> fields. I just used field-1 and field-3 to reference them, but they don't exist. I can't manipulate their styles before they get loaded.

Comment: @MarloC ok, that's a problem that will probably result in very ugly CSS-selectors to actually get the right elements if SharePoint does not let you modify the markup in any way. The concept would still stay the same though

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personally, I would use plain CSS to hide the elements and doing so by adding a class to the `body` - tag.

```
<body class="initial-hide">
  ...
</body>
```

The CSS would look something like this then

```
body.initial-hide #element1, body.initial-hide #element2{
   display: none;
}
```

This way, all you need to do to show the hidden elements is to remove the class from the body - tag to show the elements:

```
$(document).ready() {
    $('body').removeClass('initial-hide');
}
```

instead of having to select every element on it's own to call the `.show()` - function on them.

Comment: Ahh, I used body { display: none; } and just show it after all the fields are loaded.

Comment: @MarloC alright, if you want the whole page to be hidden and not just specific elements, this is an easy way to achieve this.

Comment: I only want specific elements to be hidden, but for them not to see the transition, I decided to style body as "hidden". And show it once the jQuery hide elements is done.

Comment: @GNi33 that's really clever. I like your answer more than mine :)

Comment: I used this answer but I can still see the div for a split second before the page is completely loaded.
Any idea what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

That is because your javascript fires only when the document is ready.
Use Css instead of javascript to hide the elements and load it in your page

```
<style>
#field-1,#field-3{
   display : none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I just used field-1 and field-3 to reference, I apologize for that. SharePoint doesn't really put any id nor class to the <tr> field rows. However, I figured it out by using body { display: none } and just show it after all the jQuery hiding/showing is done. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you set style="display:none;" on the element, then later with jquery you can call the .show method to make them appear.

Comment: I did it for the body { display: none } and use $('body').show() after everything is done. Thanks!